# Where can I find an "Access Mask Format" for POSIX and ACL permissions in Linux?

Tags: posix, acl, binary-flags

I was looking at NTFS file permissions yesterday, and they have an [Access Mask Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374896(v=vs.85).aspx) for their low level permissions and it's stored in an enumeration in binary, which got me wondering about if there is a similar document on POSIX and ACL permissions in Linux.

Where can I find such a document?

I know they won't be as complex (convoluted?) as the NTFS ones, but I just wondered about it anyway.

Comment: Unix permissions are famously based on octal numbers that represent binary values. If you google you can find a graphic that looks like that if you want.

Comment: [Found this in less than five seconds](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/figs/1026b.gif)

Comment: Well that covers POSIX...what about acl?